# How to read Output from Standard Console in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, output

How to read the text (on the picture it is the date and time) from Standard Console in Output and give the reference, for example, in a string variable?
I need use this text for printing in extent report.

[image: Picture: Standard Console Output]

Comment: Do you need it within Visual Studio? If not, you could call mstest with parameter /resultsfile:ResultFile.trx directly. Then you have all output including start/end dates and test results

Comment: Yes, I need it within Visual Studio. I want to add an output to extent report.